# RC Circuit with two resistors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

[image: RC Circuit]

Hello everyone, I have the RC Circuit showed in the photo but I can't figure out how to deal with it.
I need to find the time (t*) at which the capacitor has a charge on its plate of 10 microcoulomb.
At the time t*, i need also to find the current that is flowing through the generator. [V0 = 12000V; R1 = 100 ohm; R2 = 200 ohm; C = 1 nanofarad]

I know the function for an RC Circuit with one resistor [i(t), q(t), V(t)] but i don't know how this functions change in a circuit with two resistor.

Could someone explain me how to deal with such a problem? Could someone show me the functions for this type of circuit?  I'm really interested about the theory that stands behind an RC Circuit with more than one resistor.
In my course of study I've only seen the kirchhoff's law to deal with electric circuit.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: You should check your numbers. The maximum charge on this capacitor connected to 12V would be 12 nC.

Comment: Microfarads is not a unit of charge, it is capacitance. The unit for charge is coulombs. What's more, if you meant 300 microcoulombs then, as nasu pointed out, that would exceed the maximum possible charge.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It's my first question and I made some mistake with formulas.

Comment: About the errors in the numbers, sorry again. I don't have the text with me, so i writ using memory, and i made some mistake

Comment: This is a duplicate (cross post) of [this post on EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/572567/204153).

Answer (score 3):

You show two branches connected in parallel across an ideal battery.  The current in each branch is independent of the other.  If there was another resistor in series with the battery, then you would a more complex problem.

Comment: I call i1 the current trough the generator, i2 the current through R1 and i3 the current through R2. You mean that in this case i1 is not equal to i2+13?

Comment: The current from the battery is the sum of the other two. They are still independent.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the units for charge are coulombs, not microfarads which is the unit for the capacitor. And if you meant 300 microcoulombs, that would exceed the maximum possible charge of CV = 12 nC as pointed out by @nasu.

In any case, since the battery is shown to be ideal (no internal resistance) the voltage across $R_1$ is $V_0$ regardless of the value of $R_1$. This means you can ignore $R_1$ (replace it with an open circuit) leaving you with a simple series $R_{2}C$ circuit connected to a 12 volt source.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So is the current in each branch totally independent? Okay, I thought there was an addiction between current. Thanks

Comment: The fact that the battery supplies current to $R_1$ and well as to the series combination of $R_2$ and the capacitor $C$ has no effect on the time to charge the capacitor to a specific  voltage (and thus specific amount of charge). The time constant is $R_{2}C$ regardless of what $R_1$ is.

Comment: Thank you. But if the currents are indipendent, how can I calculate the current through the generator?

Comment: @Bender If you mean by "generator" you mean the 12 v battery, why do you need the current through the battery? Your post said you wanted the time it takes to charge the capacitor. Only the current through $R_2$ charges the capacitor. Anyway, the total current delivered by the battery is the sum of the current delivered to $R_1$ plus the current delivered to the series $R_{2}C$ circuit, or

Comment: $$i(t)=\frac{V_o}{R_1}+\frac{V_o}{R_2}e^{-\frac{t}{R_{2}C}}$$

Which assumes there is a switch after the battery that closes at time $t=0$ and that there is no initial voltage on the capacitor.

Comment: I understand, thank you